# cakephp 同じコードをまとめる

Tags: php, cakephp

例えば以下のようにいくつかの関数に渡って同じコードを記述する場合、ひとつにまとめてスッキリさせる方法はないのでしょうか？
詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');

class SampleController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Session');
    public $uses = array('Sample', 'User');

    public function index() {

        $this -> autoLayout = false;

　　　　　/*以下のコードが同じ*/

        if($this->Session->check('my_id')){

        $get_session = $this->Session->read('my_id');

            $this->set('get_session_id',$get_session);

        } else{

            $this->set('get_session_id',false);
        }

    }

    public function a() {

        $this -> autoLayout = false;

        if($this->Session->check('my_id')){

        $get_session = $this->Session->read('my_id');

            $this->set('get_session_id',$get_session);

        } else{

            $this->set('get_session_id',false);
        }

    }

    public function b() {

        $this -> autoLayout = false;
        if($this->Session->check('my_id')){

        $get_session = $this->Session->read('my_id');

            $this->set('get_session_id',$get_session);

        } else{

            $this->set('get_session_id',false);
        }

    }

    public function c() {

        $this -> autoLayout = false;

        if($this->Session->check('my_id')){

        $get_session = $this->Session->read('my_id');

            $this->set('get_session_id',$get_session);

        } else{

            $this->set('get_session_id',false);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

該当箇所を別のメソッドに分離すればよいです。

```
class SampleController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        $this->autoLayout = false;

        $this->someFunction();
    }

    private function someFunction()
    {
        if($this->Session->check('my_id')){

        $get_session = $this->Session->read('my_id');

            $this->set('get_session_id',$get_session);

        } else{

            $this->set('get_session_id',false);
        }
    }
}
```

もし複数のコントローラーで共通化したい場合は`AppController`に定義してください。

### AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    protected function someFunction()
    {
    }
}
```